# How to add html code based on the screen sizes using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to make add some code to the HTML dom according to the screen sizes. I want to totally remove the code when the screen size is something instead of still having the code and doing `display: none`. How can I do it?

```html
<div id="main">
  <h1>One</h1>
</div>
```

```js
const main = document.getElementById('main');

if(window.innerWidth <= 400) {
       main.innerHTML = '<h2>Added By js</h2>';
 }
 else {
 main.innerHTML = '';
 }
```

Comment: [`.matchMedia()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

Comment: I was going to tell the `resize eventListener`. but .matchMedia() would be cooler

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the @media screen of css, I think you need to do this:

```
h1{
   display: block;
  }
 h2{
   display: none;
  }

@media screen (max-width: 400px) {
 h1{
   display: none;
  }
 h2{
   display: block;
  }
 }
```

doing this you tell the browser to set `display:none` of the h1 when the screen width is over 400px, you can do it too with height

Comment: yes, but on inspect that element is present there every time, I just want to add a piece of code on some specific screen size

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it with javascript, all you're missing are the events that will trigger your code

```
function yourFunction() {
    const main = document.getElementById('main');

    if(window.innerWidth <= 400) {
       main.innerHTML = '<h2>Added By js</h2>';
    } else {
    main.innerHTML = '';
    }
}

window.onload = yourFunction;
window.onresize = yourFunction;
```

Comment: In this if we do else and make the innerHTML blank then every other HTML will also get removed, I want to just make specific HTML code to the dom and remove it when the screen size is changed

Comment: then just modify the code inside the else. remove only the element you want, not all html. like this: var el = document.getElementById('div-02');
el.remove();

Comment: how to remove that specific, like?

Comment: var el = document.getElementById('div-02'); el.remove();